# Where does the slang word "bad" + "ass" (badass) come from?

Tags: etymology, american-english, slang, offensive-language

What is the origin of the word badass? Why a "bad" ass/"bad" + "ass"? What is an ass that is bad and how can an ass that is bad describe a tough person?

Comment: It refers to a legendary stubborn donkey.

Comment: It is US 'opposite slang'.  Bad means good and ass means "not an ass".

Comment: The word is associated with rebellion, in that you're so tough you can defy other people, which would explain the word "bad" (you are bad because you are rebellious.)

Answer (score 9):

***The earliest bad-ass***

According the *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994), the word *bad-ass* is attested first as an adjective (1955), then as a noun (1956), and then as a verb (1974–1977). Here are the main entry and the three earliest occurrences identified for the adjective form:

> **bad-ass** or **bad-assed** *adj.* bad (in any common sense, esp. in slang senses).—usu. considered vulgar. Also *semi-adv.*
>
> **1955** in J. Blake, *Joint* 110. Wanted to be a hard-nosed badass type. **1958** Stack a Lee 2: There was this bad ass Indian they call Geronimo....Over in the corner sit old bad ass Stack. **1959** Abrahams, *Deep Down* 138: Before I throw open my bad-ass cashmere and pull my bad-ass gun....I had that old bad-ass Benny Long in my thirty-eight sights.

The same dictionary cites a 1971 article in *Playboy* magazine quoting the liner notes of Bo Diddley's most recent LP, which describe him as "the most outrageous bad-assed guitar man alive."

RHHDAS's entry for the noun form of the word starts this way:

> **bad-ass** *n.* **1.** A dangerous, browbeating individual; bully.—usu. considered vulgar.
>
> **1956** *A[merican] S[peech]* XXXI 191: A marine who postures toughness is sarcastically labeled a badass. **1961** Peacock, *Valhalla* 345 [ref. to Korean War]: They's a lot of bad asses at South Camp, ain't they? **1970** Ponicsan, *Last Detail* 7: Bad-Ass...in Navy parlance means a very tough customer.

And for the verb:

> **bad-ass** *v.* to bully; to behave like a bully.—usu. considered vulgar.
>
> **1974–77** Heinemann *Close Quarters* 96: "Listen," he said again, trying to bad-ass me. "When I tell you to slow down , that's exactly what I mean."

It's interesting that both the earliest adjective citation and the earliest noun citation emphasize the sarcasm implicit in the usage. To get a sense of where the construction came from, however, we need to look at the entire *-ass* family as it existed in the 1950s and 1960s.

---

***Members of the mid-20th-century* -ass *family***

Today various slang terms have *-ass* tacked onto their rear ends—and a surprisingly large number of them arose by the end of the 1950s. Here is a rundown of some of the more prominent members of this family, with first cited occurrence in the *Random House Dictionary of Historical American Slang* or in Chapman & Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995), and the first fairly reliable relevant Google Books match.

**bad ass** Earliest cited occurrence in RHHDAS: 1955 (adj.), 1956 (n.). Earliest relevant Google Books match: John Oliver Killens, [*Youngblood*](http://books.google.com/books?id=X7s4RaYO4l4C&pg=PA32&dq=%22heard+those+words+before+Bad+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V7wCVIHAC6GjigK70ICICw&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22heard%20those%20words%20before%20Bad%20ass%22&f=false) (1954) [combined snippets]:

> Joe looked down into Mr. Pete's fat face. Where had he heard those words before? **Bad ass** [racial slur]. **Smart ass** [racial slur] — He tried to remember. It was as if everything that happened had been done before — **Bad ass** [racial slur]. Feeling his entire body grow hot with anger. Control yourself, Joe. Don't get in no trouble with white folks.

Earliest relevant Google Books match for *bad-assed*: George Garrett, [*Which Ones Are the Enemy?*](http://books.google.com/books?id=EKBaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22big+and+bad-assed+and+mean%22&dq=%22big+and+bad-assed+and+mean%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N9sCVOH7IKSDjAKX3oCADg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1961) [combined snippets]:

> "Man. I like this *grappa*," he'd say. "When I get going and get high on *grappa* I'm nothing but big and **bad-assed** and mean and, buddy, you better look out. You better make way for me." That may be the way he saw himself. I would say he was the mildest, quietest kind of drunk.

**big-ass** Earliest cited occurrence in RHHDAS: 1945 (adj.), 1963–1964 (n.). Earliest relevant Google Books match: Thomas Williams, [*Town Burning*](http://books.google.com/books?id=YA2yAAAAIAAJ&q=%22big+ass%22&dq=%22big+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eL8CVK78KM6ajAKXt4GwCQ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCTge) (1959) [combined snippets]:

> Them old biddies this side of Bank Street—now I don't mean your maw, Johnny, she ain't as bad as the rest — but them big society **big-ass** biddies with their Women's Club and all. You know what I mean? Sometimes I wish I'd of stayed in the Army; they want a man to kiss their ass like that.

Earliest relevant Google Books match for *big-assed*: Irwin Shaw, [*The Young Lions*](http://books.google.com/books?id=WLXtV2s_U6QC&q=%22big+assed%22&dq=%22big+assed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8NsCVJS0FOLNiwLXxoCoCw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBjgK) (1948) [combined snippets]:

> "You-all go on ahead now and take off like a **big-assed** bird if they spot you."
>
> Noah and Burnecker looked at each other. They wanted to say something to Rickett, standing scornfully at the window, the BAR loose in his big hands, but they didn't know what to say.

**candy-ass** Earliest cited occurrence in RHHDAS: 1952 [actually 1953, referring to 1942 usage] (adj.). 1966 (n.). Earliest relevant Google Books match: Leon Uris, [*Battle Cry*](http://books.google.com/books?id=MtesVj2OD4wC&q=%22candy+ass%22&dq=%22candy+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gcMCVIqRNM6VjALDjoFI&ved=0CCEQ6AEwATgK) (1953) [snippet]:

> Huxley had the time he had bid for; he had the conditions he wanted and he spared no rods on us. And then we began to pass outfits along the route, crapped out and exhausted. “**Candy-ass** Marines,” our boys would shout as we flashed past them.

**crazy-ass** Not cited in RHHDAS or DAS: Earliest relevant Google Books match: Thomas Phillips, [*Kangaroo Hollow*](http://books.google.com/books?id=lj9bAAAAMAAJ&q=%22for+what+you+crazy+ass%22&dq=%22for+what+you+crazy+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HMwCVLW9EOPmiwKuuYDAAQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1954) [combined snippets]:

> He wanted to get back to the line and said so, in the middle of a cafe session while pretty girls walked by.
>
> "For what, you **crazy-ass** fool?" Bamey demanded.

**dumb-ass** Earliest cited occurrence in RHHDAS: 1957 (adj.), 1958 (n.). Earliest relevant Google Books match:John Oliver Killens, [*And Then We Heard the Thunder*](http://books.google.com/books?id=BvoEAQAAIAAJ&q=%22dumb+ass%22&dq=%22dumb+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bdICVLCACuS9jAKynoGwDA&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBThG) (1962) [snippet]:

> "...or some kind of hifalutin shit like that. You too educated for us **dumb-ass** colored soldiers."

**half-ass** Earliest cited occurrence in RHHDAS: 1863 (adj.), 1929–1933 (adv.), 1929–1933 (n). Earliest relevant Google Books match: Joseph Freeman, [*An American Testament*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ipEIAQAAIAAJ&q=%22half+ass%22&dq=%22half+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TscCVNDDHtD5igKx4ICwDA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBzgo) (1936) [combined snippets]:

> Robert and I liked this editorial, but Louis furiously disagreed. No socialist, he said, ought to like anything about J. P. Morgan as a social figure. There was nothing especially attractive about his belief that his money belonged to him. Every parasite believed that; he had to kid himself as well as the public. If the *Masses* editor were a real revolutionary socialist instead of a **half-ass** intellectual he would not applaud Morgan's noble attitude toward his money; he would point out where that money came from from the sweat and blood of the workers.

Earliest relevant Google Books match for *half-assed*: Travis Ingham, [*Young Gentlemen, Rise*](http://books.google.com/books?id=C0VCAAAAIAAJ&q=%22half+assed%22&dq=%22half+assed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qN8CVKa4EaTtigLe-ICICg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBzgo) (1935) [combined snippets]:

> "Of course I see," he said, taking out a pipe and filling it. "I saw it yesterday when I had to rescue you from that **half-assed** bastard from Dubuque or wherever it is that he lays sewer pipe. I knew it the night before when you refused to go to Number Thirty-two with the crowd and see an exhibition."

**jive-ass** Earliest cited occurrence in RHHDAS: 1967 (adj.). Earliest relevant Google Books match (one of many in 1969, actually): [*Esquire*](http://books.google.com/books?id=-BEgAQAAMAAJ&q=%22jive+ass%22&dq=%22jive+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sM0CVN7rDtD4igLb84HIAw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBg), volume 72 (1969) [combined snippets]:

> Suddenly a rangy Negro, a high-school student, is out of the aisle, yelling at Jenkins : "How can you sit there and tell these **jive-ass** hypocritical lies? You got this, like, **jive-ass** educational bullshit, and it's, like, one big **jive-ass**...." This word **jive-ass** starts getting to the kid. It starts wrapping around him like a turban, like a flamenco sash, like an epiphyte, like a flag, like a python, an octopus. "... I mean, like, you talk **jive-ass**, man, then you do **jive-ass**, and this hypocritical **jive-ass** ain't relevant to the Third World peoples, it's just **jive-ass**, and you sit there with both hands on the **jive-ass** hypocritical **jive-assing** **jive-ass**!"
>
> "Right on! Right on!"

**lazy-ass** Not cited in RHHDAS or DAS. Earliest relevant Google Books match: Glenn Ross, [*The Last Campaign*](http://books.google.com/books?id=g5lAAAAAIAAJ&q=%22lazy+ass%22&dq=%22lazy+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v9cCVK-HOuWKjAL-0YHwBw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCDgK) (1962) [combined snippets]:

> "Sonovabitches! Capture a perfeckly good piece of equipment, and that **lazy ass** Doglane throws it away! I wouldn't even a rolled the thing down the hill, if I'd a thought he was gonna get in on the deal."

**smart-ass** Earliest cited occurrence in DAS: "By 1960." Earliest relevant Google Books match: Leon Wilson, [*Sinners Come Away*](http://books.google.com/books?id=_5REAAAAIAAJ&q=%22smart+ass+northern%22&dq=%22smart+ass+northern%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RbgCVKGYG5S2ogTO1QI&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBA) (1949) [combined snippets]:

> Pres stepped on the man's hat as he went to the front of the cell. He kicked it back. "One of these **smart-ass** Northern boys," he said. "We'll slow him down. We'll put a string on him by God and give him to Pop for a pet."

Earliest relevant Google Books match for *smart-assed*: Ed McBain, [*The Mugger*](http://books.google.com/books?id=r9FaAAAAYAAJ&q=%22smart+assed%22&dq=%22smart+assed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=T-ECVJeXBOKJjAL06oGoBQ&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBTgU) (1956) [combined snippets]:

> The little girl goes with them to Reno—Dad conveniently has business there at the same time Mom must establish residence—and through an unvarying progression of mincing postures and bright-eyed, smirking little-girl facial expressions, convinces Mom and Dad to stay together eternally and live in connubial bliss with their mincing, bright-eyed, smirking little **smart-assed** daughter.

---

***Are the asses biblical donkeys or mammalian posteriors?***

The upsurge in *-ass* compounds in the 1950s follows some crucial precedents. First, both *half-ass* (by 1936) and *half-assed* (by 1935) were established forms; and second, so were *big-ass* (1945, according to RHHDAS) and *big-assed* (1948). Another form already in place was *smart-ass* (1949).

There are strong reasons to suppose that *half-ass* arose originally in reference to the mule (half-ass and half-horse), but it's harder to argue that everyone in 1950 was on board with this etymology. After all, if "mule" were the idea in all writers' and speakers' minds, why would any of them express the adjective as *half-assed* instead of as *half-ass* (or maybe *half-asinine*)?

In my view, the more plausible explanation is that when the flood of *-asses* inundated the language in the 1950s and 1960s, English speakers were already divided on the question of what the -*ass* referred to in any particular case. As a result, we often see both *-ass* and *-assed* forms—and even within the *-ass* segment of speakers and writers, the association with hooved beasts of burden is far from unanimous.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189071/changes-in-meaning-of-bad-and-bad-ass/189072#189072) on how the meanings of *bad* and other similar words have changed over time (and actually it was a dupe, and the previous questions' answers may be just as good).  The comment on my answer is spot on—that words have often tended to just reverse their meaning.

If you imagine, at one point, the meaning of the word *badass* to be the opposite of what it is now—someone actually *bad* (negatively), it makes much more sense.  *Ass* has often been used to pejoratively refer to someone stupid, or to insult people, and appending *bad* sounds just about right.

I'd say *badass*, at face value, sounds like it is meant in a negative way, to mean someone who is belligerent or reckless (a bad ass/bad donkey?), so people started using it to mean the opposite.  Similar to how other words that imply *danger* have changed over time to mean something positive (because danger is sometimes seen as cool), *badass* may have at some point changed to mean someone who is dangerous or reckless in a *cool* way.

*note: I am not saying that the word badass was actually meant in a bad way at some point—just suggesting that thinking about it that way might help it make sense.*

Answer (score 1):

According to Etymonline.com:

[Badass](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=badass&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.) [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=badass%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbadass%3B%2Cc0)

> "tough guy," 1950s U.S. slang, from bad + ass (n.2).

[Ass](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Ass&searchmode=none) (n.2)

> slang for "backside," first attested 1860 in nautical slang, in popular use from 1930; chiefly U.S.; from dialectal variant pronunciation of arse (q.v.). The loss of -r- before -s- attested in several other words (such as burst/bust, curse/cuss, horse/hoss, barse/bass). *Indirect evidence of the change from arse to ass can be traced to 1785 (in euphemistic avoidance of ass "donkey" by polite speakers) and perhaps to Shakespeare, if Nick Bottom transformed into a donkey in "A Midsummer Night's Dream" (1594) is the word-play some think it is. Meaning "woman regarded as a sexual object" is from 1942. **Colloquial (one's) ass "one's self, one's person" attested by 1958**.

Comment: My guess is that @JohnLawler is right here, wrt *ass*. It's about the stubbornness or unruliness of a donkey; it is not about a human "backside".

Comment: Wow, two users who suicided in one question