# Changes in meaning of "bad" and "bad ass"

Tags: etymology

How did the definition of *bad* change over time? When did it change to mean *good*?

Answer (score 2):

[*Bad* has been used to mean *good* since the 1800s.](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/05/inverted-meanings-sick/)

The meaning of many, many words in English change over time.  Many times they go back to a previous meaning.  It's nothing new with the word *bad*.  Another similar example is *sick* which since roughly the 80s in America has been used to also mean *good* or *excellent*.

If you really want to know *why* in particular *bad* has been used to mean good, a possible explanation is that many people see dangerous and reckless things as impressive.  The thing I linked in the first sentence says how *sick* was used in skate culture to mean something *good* because risk and danger are considered good in that culture.

Comment: I wouldn't completely dismiss your "why" part, but I think in most cases it's just that slang has a general tendency to adopt "meaning reversal" usages - which is why you'll also often hear an exasperated *"Well that's **good**, innit?"* in the UK (where an earlier generation might have said *"That's another **fine** mess you've gotten us into!"*).

Comment: You're right, @FumbleFingers. I just wanted to give *something* besides *it just happens a lot*.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted you. I didn't vote at all because so far as I was concerned the Q is a dup anyway. But have my +1 to counteract injustice, 'cos even if your "possible explanation" doesn't *often* apply, it is specific to the particular word being queried here (I was just referring to the more general tendency).

Comment: Thank you ☺️. The post I linked is general enough that I saw a small chance this wouldn't be closed—given a decent edit—so I answered it anyway.